# If a function $f(x)$ implicitly depends on time, can you take its time derivative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, soft-question, physics

Suppose I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

$y = f(x)$

But $x$ is the solution to a differential equation $\dot x = g(x)$, so it depends on time.

Can I take the time derivative of $f$ even though it is not defined as a function of time?

---

Note: my confusion is that $f$ is not a function that explicitly depends on time, i.e. the argument of $f$ is not time.

Comment: I'm assuming your differential equation is $$\frac{dx}{dt}=g(x)$$ and $x$ is a function of $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as your function is really
$$y=f(x(t))$$
Its derivative is therefore
$$f'(x(t))\cdot g(x(t))$$
by the chain rule and since $x'(t)=g(x(t))$.

Comment: Even though it is the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: If $f$ depends only on $x(t)$ and $x$ depends only on $t$, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know what cases would there be a problem?

Comment: As long as my comment holds, then no.